# Use column number instead of column name

Tags: sql-server

I have given `string name, int colnum`, which I put into Sql Parameters.

Then I want to search a table for the single data set `where name=@name and` "the value in column number `@colnum` is maximal" (in fact, I only need that maximum).

How would I do this in MSSQL?

Comment: Why don't you know the name of the column?

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to return just the maximum ColNum from the table

```
SELECT max([Name Of ColNum Column In SQL]) FROM [Sql Table]
```

if you wanted to get the Name and the maximum ColNum then you could do

```
SELECT [Name of Name Column In SQL], [Name Of ColNum Column In SQL] FROM [Sql Table] WHERE [Name Of ColNum Column In SQL] = @ColNum
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, should be like this:

```
SELECT name, colnum
FROM someTable
WHERE name=@name 
AND colnum = (SELECT MAX(colnum) FROM someTalble WHERE name=@name)
```

OR like this

```
SELECT name, MAX(colnum)
FROM someTable
WHERE name=@name 
GROUP BY name
```